# Paging in jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, loops, jstl

Using the JSTL, I am able to show the first 40 photos (declaring it in static manner). However, I wish to implement a paging table where it can dynamically display the photos in respective page.

```
<c:forEach begin="0" end="39" items="${photosList}" var="photo" varStatus="loopStatus">
    //Retrieve each photo from list and display
</c:forEach>
```

I am thinking to do it using queryString, but I am wondering if there is a more efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of implementing this yourself, I would suggest you to use some opensource library.

***Display Tag*** (***http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/***) is one of such librrary that can help you add pagination capability to your data.

This ***custom JSTL library*** also ease the implementation of tabular data in your web application in several areas. ***Do explore it beyond it's paging capability.***

Comment: Looking at the displayTag, for my case of loading the image out from the photosList, how should I go about setting the column and row? `<display:table name="photosList" pagesize="20" sort="external" partialList="true" id="photo">` Let says I wish to display 4 photos in a row.